# UITableViewCell section set and display data into section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have main array(`CartPProductListArray`) like this

```
  data=
 {
  data =  (
            {
        "cart_id" = 760;
        "cart_quantity" = 1;
        "image_url" = "http://web-medico.com/web2/kibbeh/uploads/14776327941523279103.jpg";
        name = "Milk Test ";
        price = "2.34";
        "product_id" = 44;
        "store_id" = 3;
    },
            {
        "cart_id" = 760;
        "cart_quantity" = 1;
        "image_url" = "http://web-medico.com/web2/kibbeh/uploads/14776327911430225702.jpg";
        name = "Fish Test ";
        price = "2.34";
        "product_id" = 43;
        "store_id" = 3;
    },
            {
        "cart_id" = 760;
        "cart_quantity" = 1;
        "image_url" = "http://web-medico.com/web2/kibbeh/uploads/14877289882050445800.jpg";
        name = "Cortas Apricot Jam ";
        price = "3.62";
        "product_id" = 77;
        "store_id" = 7;
    }
);
msg = "Data Found";
status = 1;
}
```

Now, I filtered this two array store wise(**store_id**)
LebaneseStoreArray(**store_id**=3) and BabylonStoreArray(**store_id**=7)

```
lenbanese==(
    (
            {
        "cart_id" = 760;
        "cart_quantity" = 1;
        "image_url" = "http://web-medico.com/web2/kibbeh/uploads/14776327941523279103.jpg";
        name = "Milk Test ";
        price = "2.34";
        "product_id" = 44;
        "store_id" = 3;
    },
            {
        "cart_id" = 760;
        "cart_quantity" = 1;
        "image_url" = "http://web-medico.com/web2/kibbeh/uploads/14776327911430225702.jpg";
        name = "Fish Test ";
        price = "2.34";
        "product_id" = 43;
        "store_id" = 3;
       }
    )
)
 babylon==(
    (
    {
        "cart_id" = 760;
        "cart_quantity" = 1;
        "image_url" = "http://web-medico.com/web2/kibbeh/uploads/14877289882050445800.jpg";
        name = "Cortas Apricot Jam ";
        price = "3.62";
        "product_id" = 77;
        "store_id" = 7;
      }
  )
)
```

In my `UITableViewCell` there are two section(**labansese and babylon**)
this is my code in `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
if(section == 1)
{
    return LebaneseStoreArray.count;
}
else if (section == 2)
{
    return BabylonStoreArray.count;
}
else
{
    return CartPProductListArray.count;
}
```

But, its getting this(check image)[image]

I want the product in cart store wise.

Please help me with this

thanks in advance.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CartCustomCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CartCell"];
    if (Cell == nil)
    {
        Cell = [[CartCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CartCell"];
    }

    Cell.ProductNameLabel.text = [[CartPProductListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    Cell.ProductPriceLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[[[CartPProductListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"price"] stringValue]];
    Cell.ProductQuantityTextField.text =[[[CartPProductListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"cart_quantity"] stringValue];

    [Cell.ProductImageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[CartPProductListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image_url"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];

    [Cell.PlusQuantityButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PlusQuantityButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    Cell.PlusQuantityButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [Cell.MinunQuantityButton addTarget:self action:@selector(MinusQuantityButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    Cell.MinunQuantityButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    return Cell;
}
```

help me with this i'm new in ios.

Comment: What about your section 0? What do you want in there and how did you set it?

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [storename3 count];
}
In Storename3 array there are two object(store) lebanese and babylon

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NSSortDescriptor` to sort your array.

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"storeID",ascending:true,selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCompare(_:)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print the  array in log. if you getting current array. 
I think the problem is inside the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { // here your code}
```

Check the array is loading inside the cellfor row at indexpath. 
// its always loading first arrary. Change the array depends on the section.

Comment: Okay, i will check it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your `numberOfRowsInSection` like this:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
    {
        return LebaneseStoreArray.count;
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        return BabylonStoreArray.count;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

For Cell for Row use below code :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CartCustomCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CartCell"];
    if (Cell == nil)
    {
        Cell = [[CartCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CartCell"];
    }

    // For Section 1 : Lebanese Store Data
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        Cell.ProductNameLabel.text = [[LebaneseStoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
        Cell.ProductPriceLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[[[LebaneseStoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"price"] stringValue]];
        Cell.ProductQuantityTextField.text =[[[LebaneseStoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"cart_quantity"] stringValue];

        [Cell.ProductImageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[LebaneseStoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image_url"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];

    }else if (indexPath.section == 0){ // For Section 2 : Babylon Store Data
        Cell.ProductNameLabel.text = [[BabylonStoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
        Cell.ProductPriceLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[[[BabylonStoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"price"] stringValue]];
        Cell.ProductQuantityTextField.text =[[[BabylonStoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"cart_quantity"] stringValue];

        [Cell.ProductImageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[BabylonStoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image_url"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
    }

    [Cell.PlusQuantityButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PlusQuantityButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    Cell.PlusQuantityButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [Cell.MinunQuantityButton addTarget:self action:@selector(MinusQuantityButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    Cell.MinunQuantityButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    return Cell;
}
```

Comment: How many object in your array LebaneseStoreArray & BabylonStoreArray ?

Comment: two object in lebanese and one object in babylon.

Comment: than how it can be possible that you got count properly and not showing cell in tableView? please post your cell for row and numberof rows method in your question so we can get idea whats going wrong ?

Comment: As per your edited question there is no use of LebaneseStoreArray & BabylonStoreArray in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ? why ? any specific reason ?

Comment: actually i don't have idea how to use it thats why i ask question.
i'm new in ios. so, i want to learn logic perfectly.